# Is there a way to determine which Exchange 2010 CAS server a user is connecting to on the server-side?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

We have a couple of CAS servers behind a hardware load balancer. We are looking to add a few more. Our normal procedure for determining which CAS server a user is connected to is:

1. Find out the IP address of the user's workstation
2. Check the loadbalancer for where the connection was directed to

However, that has proven to be challenging. We know there's a way to [determine your CAS server via OWA](https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/NETADMINWIKI/Find+the+user%27s+CASHUB+server).

Is there a way to do this server-side by username (not by IP)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, with this?

Comment: When users complain about certain issues, we've have at times narrowed it down to a single CAS server. It's taken a lot of leg work to isolate it though.

Comment: You can enable RPC logging and just gc \*.log |select-string $username on each server to find where they're hitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have so far.

For Outlook MAPI:

```
Get-LogonStatistics -Identity beamin | where {$_.applicationid -eq "Client=MSExchangeRPC"}| fl clientname,applicationid
```

For IMAP:

```
Get-LogonStatistics -Identity beamin | where {$_.applicationid -eq "Client=IMAP4"}| fl clientname,applicationid
```

I wish I could get the IP address of the client as well. There's a field that says "ClientIPAddress" field but, in my testing thus far, it's always empty. Maybe because of the load balancer?

I am hoping there's a more appropriate cmdlet for this. Any input would be appreciated.

Here are my sources:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124415(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: As far as there is no Exchange Powershell cmdlet for that, i think your solution is one of the best approach ! I think i will use it ;)